# How to add multiple date rows at once in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series

I have a dataframe with a date index, a Sales column, and a Store Number column. I want to fill in missing sales values for stores that have missing sales data.

For example, say I want to fill in missing sales values with the mean sales for the year for store 10 below. Say the sales data I have for store 10 for 2015 is:

```
Sales| Store Number| Date
4000 |      10     | 2015-01-01
6000 |      10     | 2015-01-02
10000|      10     | 2016-01-01
```

If that is the only sales data I have for store 10 for 2015, I would then want to create 363 new rows, corresponding to dates 2015-01-03 to 2015-12-31, with the mean sales of mean(4000,6000)=5000. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to find the mean sales based on the current dataset, via `groupby` Year and Store Number.
2. Then impute the mean sales for days left till end of year.

The coding of this should be fairly straightforward..

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `reindex` to get all Dates for each store + `fillna` to replace missing dates with the average sales.

```
import pandas as pd
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [df['Store Number'].unique(),
         pd.date_range(f'{df.Date.dt.year.min()}-01-01', 
                       f'{df.Date.dt.year.max()}-12-31', freq='D')])

df = df.set_index(['Store Number', 'Date']).reindex(idx)

# Mean per year by store. 
s = df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0), 
                df.index.get_level_values(1).year]).transform('mean')

df['Sales'] = df[['Sales']].fillna(s)
```

---

print(df)

```
#                Sales
#10 2015-01-01   4000.0
#   2015-01-02   6000.0
#   2015-01-03   5000.0
#   2015-01-04   5000.0
#   2015-01-05   5000.0
#...                ...
#   2016-12-27  10000.0
#   2016-12-28  10000.0
#   2016-12-29  10000.0
#   2016-12-30  10000.0
#   2016-12-31  10000.0
#[731 rows x 1 columns]
```

---

Because the `reindex` is over the cartesian product, instead of slowly reindexing each group, we can deal with stores that never have any sales and drop them after the fact.

```
m = (df['Sales'].isnull()
       .groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0), 
                 df.index.get_level_values(1).year]).transform('all'))

df = df.loc[~m]
```